# Special characters issue in Localstorage for IE8

Tags: jquery, html, character-encoding, internet-explorer-8

I have written a jQuery code which makes a call to a service, get the data and store it in the local-storage. On a particular event the data gets displayed in the page.

I am facing issue with the Chinese characters only on IE8+ browser. IE is not able to read the Chinese data from cache and displaying square boxes in place of "首选语言已更新首 选语言已更新". The same code is working as expected on other browsers like chrome and FF.

Answer (score 0):

If you see square boxes, the odds are that this is a font issue, rather than a character-level problem. That is, IE probably recognizes the characters correctly but fails to render them.

So this probably depends on the context where the characters are displayed, especially the applicable font settings. Normally, IE 8 and newer can be expected to be able to display Chinese characters, but font settings may prevent this. Besides, it’s possible that some Windows installations lack any font that supports Chinese characters.

I’d suggest that you first test whether the string is properly displayed on IE when it appears as static content on a page with no font settings.